# Build Makefile for project have multiple directories

Tags: c, makefile

I'm building a project have tree as following:

```
.
├── build
├── inc
│   └── log.h
├── Makefile
└── src
    └── ota.c
```

"src" directory contain source files .c;
"inc" contain header files .h;
"build" will contain object files .o and execute file.
Makefile details:

```
vpath %.h inc
vpath %.c src
RED         = \033[1;31m
GREEN       = \033[1;32m
YELLOW      = \033[1;33m
BLUE        = \033[1;34m
RESET       = \033[1;0m
INC_DIR     = inc
SRC_DIR     = src
BUILD_DIR   = build
CC          = gcc
CFLAGS      = -Wall -I$(INC_DIR)
RM          = rm -rf
SRCS        = $(wildcard */*.c)
INCS        = $(wildcard */*.h)
OBJS        = $(patsubst %,$(BUILD_DIR)/%,$(patsubst 
%.c,%.o,$(notdir $(SRCS))))
TARGET      = OTA


$(BUILD_DIR)/$(TARGET): $(OBJS)
    @echo "$(YELLOW)Linking ...$(RESET)"
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $^
    @echo Finished!

$(BUILD_DIR)/%.o: %.c %.h
    @echo "$(GREEN)Compiling objects ...$(RESET)"
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

.PHONY: clean
clean:
    @echo "$(RED)$(OBJS) $(SRCS) $(INCS) $(RESET)"
    $(RM) $(BUILD_DIR)/*
```

When I run make by terminal on Ubuntu 20.04 then encouter an error as below:

```
minh@Minh:~/Workspaces/OTA-tool$ make
make: *** No rule to make target 'build/ota.o', needed by 'build/OTA'.  Stop.
```

Please, tell me why error and help me fix it. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The basic problem is this:

```
OBJS = $(patsubst %,$(BUILD_DIR)/%,$(patsubst %.c,%.o,$(notdir $(SRCS))))
```

By setting `OBJS` to a value without the pathname, now make can no longer match up the object filename to the source filename.

So for example if you have `src/foo.c`, then `OBJ` will be `build/foo.o`.  Then this pattern rule:

```
$(BUILD_DIR)/%.o: %.c %.h
```

does not match, because the `%` in the target matches `foo`, which means make will be looking for `foo.c` (which doesn't exist, it's `src/foo.c`) and `foo.h` (which also doesn't exist).

Since the prerequisites don't match, this pattern rule doesn't match.  And since no other pattern rules match, make says it doesn't have any rule which knows how to create the target `build/foo.o`.

One way to solve this is to add the directories on the prerequisite as well:

```
$(BUILD_DIR)/%.o: src/%.c inc/%.h
```

Now make will look for `src/foo.c` and `inc/foo.h`.

Comment: Thank you so much, I just fix code at 2 locations and it run pretty properly: `OBJS = $(patsubst %.c,%.o,$(notdir $(SRCS)))`  and `$(BUILD_DIR)/%.o: $(SRC_DIR)/%.c $(INC_DIR)/%.h`. But it have a problem, object file not put into **build** directory like this: `minh@PCDESIGN:~/Workspaces/OTA-tool$ ls`   `build inc Makefile ota.o src`  
    Please tell me how can I do it?

Comment: There's no way we can know the answer based on the information you provided.  Are all the object files in the base directory, or just this one?  Do *both* `src/ota.c` *and* `inc/ota.h` actually exist?  Are you sure that this object fie isn't just a leftover from a previous incorrect build (if you delete it and run `make` does it come back)?

Comment: This project just have an empty `build` directory to contain object file `.o` and execute file after run `make`; `inc` drectory contain header file `log.h`; `src` directory contain source file `ota.c` and a `Makefile` as tree above. I'm sure deleted all object file before I run `make`. My problem is that `ota.o` file not put into `build` but put in base driectory.

Comment: You have two problems.  First by removing the `$(BUILD_DIR)` from the `OBJS` variable you are asking make to build `ota.o`, not `build/ota.o`, so that's what it does.  Second, you have defined a rule `$(BUILD_DIR)/%.o: $(SRC_DIR)/%.c $(INC_DIR)/%.h`.  This rule cannot match unless **BOTH** the appropriate `src/xxx.c` **AND** `inc/xxx.h` files exist.  Since you don't have a `inc/ota.h`, this rule doesn't match.  It's highly unusual to add a pattern for a header AND a source file, unless you are 100% sure that every single source file has an associated header.